# Get polygons from JSON request in an ArcGIS webmap

Tags: geojson, arcgis-online, web-mapping, arcgis-online-webmap

I'm trying to scrape some polygons from an ArcGIS webmap, and outside requests/ REST API don't work. I want to take the polygons I see in the webmap and turn them into a shapefile.

The webmap of polygons is here: https://mogov.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=836f4943866540a3b01d83f8ff8d9d4f

The request is:

```
https://utility.arcgis.com/usrsvcs/servers/bcbd629c3be8490dbce4179a7ac46c6c/rest/services/DED/ARPAbroadbandgrantawards_prime/MapServer/0/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry=%7B%22xmin%22%3A-10488383.273191104%2C%22ymin%22%3A4657155.259379331%2C%22xmax%22%3A-10449247.514709145%2C%22ymax%22%3A4696291.017861288%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%7D%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=102100&outFields=*&outSR=102100&quantizationParameters=%7B%22mode%22%3A%22view%22%2C%22originPosition%22%3A%22upperLeft%22%2C%22tolerance%22%3A76.43702828507467%2C%22extent%22%3A%7B%22xmin%22%3A-10600540.5497%2C%22ymin%22%3A4364518.704800002%2C%22xmax%22%3A-10014872.906%2C%22ymax%22%3A4951055.066200003%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A3857%2C%22xyTolerance%22%3A0.001%2C%22zTolerance%22%3A0.001%2C%22mTolerance%22%3A0.001%2C%22falseX%22%3A-20037700%2C%22falseY%22%3A-30241100%2C%22xyUnits%22%3A10000%2C%22falseZ%22%3A-100000%2C%22zUnits%22%3A10000%2C%22falseM%22%3A-100000%2C%22mUnits%22%3A10000%7D%7D%7D


The responses look like:
```

```json
{
  "displayFieldName": "Entity_Name",
  "transform": {
    "originPosition": "upperLeft",
    "scale": [ 76.43702828507467, 76.43702828507467 ],
    "translate": [ -10600540.5497,4951055.066200003 ]
  },
  "fieldAliases": {
    "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID",
    "Entity_Name": "Entity_Name",
    "Project_Name": "Project_Name",
    "Technology": "Type of Technology Deployed",
    "Speed": "Proposed Connection Speed",
    "SubmissionID": "SubmissionID",
    "Connections": "Number of Connections",
    "GlobalID": "GlobalID",
    "created_user": "created_user",
    "created_date": "created_date",
    "last_edited_user": "last_edited_user",
    "last_edited_date": "last_edited_date",
    "Shape.STArea()": "Shape.STArea()",
    "Shape.STLength()": "Shape.STLength()"
  },
  "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
  "spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 102100,
    "latestWkid": 3857
  },
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "OBJECTID",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
      "alias": "OBJECTID"
    },
    {
      "name": "Entity_Name",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
      "alias": "Entity_Name",
      "length": 255
    },
    {
      "name": "Project_Name",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
      "alias": "Project_Name",
      "length": 255
    },
    {
      "name": "Technology",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
      "alias": "Type of Technology Deployed",
      "length": 255
    },
    {
      "name": "Speed",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
      "alias": "Proposed Connection Speed",
      "length": 255
    },
    {
      "name": "SubmissionID",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeInteger",
      "alias": "SubmissionID"
    },
    {
      "name": "Connections",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeSmallInteger",
      "alias": "Number of Connections"
    },
    {
      "name": "GlobalID",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeGlobalID",
      "alias": "GlobalID",
      "length": 38
    },
    {
      "name": "created_user",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
      "alias": "created_user",
      "length": 255
    },
    {
      "name": "created_date",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeDate",
      "alias": "created_date",
      "length": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "last_edited_user",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
      "alias": "last_edited_user",
      "length": 255
    },
    {
      "name": "last_edited_date",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeDate",
      "alias": "last_edited_date",
      "length": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "Shape.STArea()",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
      "alias": "Shape.STArea()"
    },
    {
      "name": "Shape.STLength()",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
      "alias": "Shape.STLength()"
    }
  ],
  "features": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "OBJECTID": 55,
        "Entity_Name": "Osage Valley Electric Cooperative Association",
        "Project_Name": "Osage Valley FTTH Project B",
        "Technology": "Fiber",
        "Speed": "Greater than or equal to 100 Mbps / 100 Mbps ",
        "SubmissionID": 32690937,
        "Connections": 1055,
        "GlobalID": "{D54B90A6-ABD7-4A37-B589-8F7302A37CC7}",
        "created_user": null,
        "created_date": null,
        "last_edited_user": null,
        "last_edited_date": null,
        "Shape.STArea()": 162837519.2421875,
        "Shape.STLength()": 145659.22475947847
      },
      "geometry": {
        "rings": [
          [[1031,3723],[7,2],[10,-2],[8,2],[13,0],[8,1],[8,7],[17,14],[4,7],[4,4],[16,4],[4,2],[-1,9],[-1,13],[20,0],[0,3],[2,37],[-28,-3],[0,6],[-14,-2],[-19,-1],[1,20],[-11,-2],[-33,-14],[-27,-1],[-10,-5],[-2,-3],[-1,-2],[-2,-3],[-4,-2],[-5,0],[-6,-1],[-5,0],[-6,-1],[-3,1],[1,-20],[-20,-1],[0,-28],[16,-26],[9,-13],[1,-21],[17,-1],[13,6],[14,9],[5,5]],
          [[2503,4290],[17,6],[14,-1],[14,3],[12,8],[0,10],[-5,1],[-7,-2],[-3,0],[-1,0],[1,5],[9,4],[4,3],[5,15],[3,20],[2,11],[-8,-2],[-8,-2],[-2,-12],[-6,-13],[-7,-3],[-3,2],[-5,-1],[0,-4],[0,-3],[0,-5],[-1,-1],[-2,-1],[-5,2],[-5,5],[-4,-3],[-3,-4],[-2,-3],[-5,0],[-3,6],[2,7],[2,4],[4,5],[6,12],[0,10],[-8,8],[-11,1],[-10,-18],[3,-86],[2,5],[6,3],[8,8]],
          [[1670,4254],[0,2],[-5,0],[-5,0],[-4,0],[0,5],[0,1],[1,0],[3,1],[1,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,3],[-5,-1],[-10,-12],[-65,-9],[1,-25],[71,2],[2,1],[-1,27],[7,3],[7,1]],
          [[1489,4217],[0,3],[-1,0],[-1,0],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[2,0]],
          [[1461,4217],[0,15],[-4,0],[0,-15],[4,0]],
          [[1691,4197],[-1,0],[0,-1],[1,0],[0,1]],
          [[1607,4184],[-2,0],[0,-1],[1,0],[1,0],[0,1]],
          [[1767,4185],[0,1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[0,-1],[1,0],[-1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,1],[-1,0]],
          [[1470,4182],[0,-1],[1,0],[0,1],[-1,0]],
          [[1721,4144],[-1,0],[-1,0],[1,0],[1,0]],
          [[1645,4115],[-1,0],[0,-1],[1,0],[0,1]],
          [[1599,4106],[23,15],[-21,-1],[0,-7],[-2,0],[0,-7]],
          [[1480,4103],[0,1],[-1,-1],[-1,0],[2,0]],
          [[1525,4109],[-1,1],[-1,1],[-23,-1],[1,3],[-1,2],[-1,3],[-13,-1],[0,-18],[40,1],[0,7],[-1,0],[0,2]],
          [[1775,4097],[-2,1],[-2,-1],[0,-6],[3,0],[2,0],[0,3],[-1,3]],
          [[1549,4077],[0,1],[-22,-1],[1,-12],[21,12]],
          [[1481,4059],[0,1],[-1,0],[0,-1],[1,0]],
          [[1139,3854],[-1,62],[-68,-3],[2,-40],[41,1],[1,0],[1,-1],[1,-1],[1,-1],[0,-3],[1,-2],[1,-2],[3,-3],[3,-3],[2,-1],[5,-1],[7,-2]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to piece this response back together into a shapefile or GeoJSON somehow?

Answer (score 1):

To get **GeoJSON**

you will need to use a url like

```
https://gis.mo.gov/arcgis01/rest/services/DED/Broadband_Projects/MapServer/1/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&having=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&f=geojson
```

Then save as a GeoJSON file.

In **QGIS** you can load that ArcGIS Feature Server/Services in directly. Then Export out as shapefile/geojson.

[image]